# Can you make a list of Pointers in C#?

Tags: c#, pointers, dependency-properties

If I have a group of DependencyProperties:

```
public UIElement Button0
{
    get { return (UIElement)GetValue(Button1Property); }
    set { SetValue(Button1Property, value); }
}
public static DependencyProperty Button1Property = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Button1), typeof(UIElement), typeof(myClass), new PropertyMetadata(null));


public UIElement Button1....

public UIElement Button2....

...
```

Is there a way to create an observable collection of those properties, such that

```
AllButtons[0] = new Button(); //actually does: SetValue(Button0Property, value);
var button = AllButtons[1]; // actually does button = (UIElement)GetValue(Button1Property);
```

I've been struggling with this for a while, and was hoping that the new [**ref** return values in C# 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns)  would do this easily, but yet again I've hit a brick wall. Isn't there some way in C# to make a list of pointers to properties?

Comment: If you share the attempt you’ve made, it would likely generate better answers.

Comment: When you are working with _Reference Types_ in C#, what your variables represent is a reference to an object created on the heap. If you say `var b1 = new Button(); var b2 = b1; b2.Text = "New Text";` and then look at b1's Text property, you will see that it changed (since both b1 and b2 refer to the same object).  If you add b1 to a collection, the reference in the collection and b1 (and b2) now all refer to the same button.  C# doesn't have pointers in normal (aka "safe") code, but it has references for free for everything but _Value Types_